# group by is messing up my counts mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement, group-by

I have a basic table:

```
id  client  trans_date  returned
1    bob    20180301       0
2    frank  20180301       0
3    bob    20180401       1
```

id like to get a result that groups by the client and counts how many items bought and how many returned. Like this

```
name  bought returned
bob    1       1
frank  1       0
```

i tried this but it didnt work

```
SELECT 
     soldto AS name,
     IF(return=0,count(id),'0') AS bought,
     IF(return=1,count(id),'0') AS returned 
FROM sales 
WHERE sdate BETWEEN '20180201000000' AND '20180501000000'
group by soldto;
```

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: Looks like  `bob` bought 2 and return 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT 
     soldto AS name,
     COUNT(*) AS bought,
     -- or maybe COUNT( CASE WHEN return = 0 THEN 1 END) AS bought,
     COUNT( CASE WHEN return = 1 THEN 1 END) AS returned 
FROM sales 
WHERE sdate BETWEEN '20180201000000' AND '20180501000000'
GROUP BY soldto;
```

Comment: I used a sum instead of count

select 
client AS name,
sum(CASE returnitem WHEN '0' then 1 else 0 end) as bought,
sum(CASE returnitem WHEN '1' then 1 else 0 end) as returned
from sales
WHERE sdate between '20180201000000' and '20180501000000' 
GROUP BY client

Comment: I like use `COUNT()` to count. If you don't include `ELSE` for the `CASE` return `NULL` and `COUNT()` doesn't count null